# Cell containing text with another requirements

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do a IF with 3 ANDs. I need only 1 IF command and it should fulfill 3 requirements

```
value of cell a1 should be more than 5
value of cell a2 should not be "True"
value of cell a3 should not contain "shop"
```

First two are easy to predict, but i do not know how to do 3rd operation, because in vba there is no something like not like. I can not use IF in IF, so i took this
InStr(CELL which i check, "shop") = 0, and it should show me 0 = 0 if there is no any shop in cell right? But still not working :P

```
IF Cells(1,1).Value > 5 And Cells(2,1).Value <> "True" And InStr(Cells(3,1).Value,"shop") = 0 Then
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question.

Comment: i have updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple concatenated logic tests are often much easier to manage and understand if you encapsulate them in a function

For example the complex test of

```
IF Cells(1,1).Value > 5 And Cells(1,1).Value <> "True" And InStr(Cells(3,1).Value,"shop") = 0 Then
```

Might be better written as

```
If not TryYourTestName(Cells(1,1).Value,Cells(1,1).Value,Cells(3,1).Value) then 'do action when test fails
'Do actions when test passes
```

With the function

```
Public Function TryYourTestName(ByVal ipA1 As Long, ByVal ipA2 As Boolean, ByVal ipA3 As String) As Boolean

    TryYourTestName = False
    If ipA1 <= 5 Then Exit Function
    If ipA2 Then Exit Function
    If InStr(ipA3, "Shop") <> 0 Then Exit Function
    TryYourName = True

End Function
```